# AWS Ruby SDK Pricing gem Aws::Errors::NoSuchEndpointError

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I've been working with other gems in this SDK and haven't seen this issue before. I'm trying to create a Pricing client and get some service descriptions but I'm getting this exception and I'm not sure why:

```
require 'aws-sdk-pricing'

c = Aws::Pricing::Client.new(region: 'eu-west-1')
r = c.describe_services({ format_version: "aws_v1", max_results: 1, 
  service_code: "AmazonEC2" })
```

and I get:

> Aws::Errors::NoSuchEndpointError: Encountered a `SocketError` while
>   attempting to connect to:
>
> https://api.pricing.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
>
> This is typically the result of an invalid `:region` option or a
>   poorly formatted `:endpoint` option.
>
> - Avoid configuring the `:endpoint` option directly. Endpoints are constructed   from the `:region`. The `:endpoint` option is reserved
>     for connecting to   non-standard test endpoints.
> - Not every service is available in every region.
> - Never suffix region names with availability zones.   Use "us-east-1", not "us-east-1a"
>
> Known AWS regions include (not specific to this service):
>
> ap-northeast-1 ap-northeast-2 ap-south-1 ap-southeast-1 ap-southeast-2
>   ca-central-1 eu-central-1 eu-west-1 eu-west-2 sa-east-1 us-east-1
>   us-east-2 us-west-1 us-west-2 cn-north-1 us-gov-west-1

I've tried this in other regions and get the same results. The same pattern in other gems, like aws-sdk-ec2, allows me to instance a client without an issue. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Using ruby 2.3.3 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out at the writing of this question AWS only supports this API at 2 endpoints: us-east-1 and ap-south-1.  See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-pelong.html

You can specify the region from which you'd like prices in the request.